# Connection Issue - Unable to connect to database server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this message in my site all of a sudden without making any changes in the config file. I will post my config code to see if there are any issues with it.

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'www.victorexoticagoa.com');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', '******');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '********');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'victor');
define('USE_PCONNECT', 'false');
define('STORE_SESSIONS', 'mysql');
define('CFG_TIME_ZONE', 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

The above code is from the configure.php file.

The below code is the connection:

```
tep_db_connect() or die('Unable to connect to database server!');
```

And the code below is the function which does the connection:

```
  function tep_db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link') {
global $$link;

if (USE_PCONNECT == 'true') {
  $server = 'p:' . $server;
}

$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

if ( !mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
  mysqli_set_charset($$link, 'utf8');
} 

return $$link;
}
```

Any help will be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I always use `localhost` as DB_SERVER.

Comment: Have you checked if your database server is up?

Comment: actually it isn't, is that the reason why?

Comment: Yes. That is the reason why.

Comment: Try to edit configuration to allow remote access [How to allow remote connection to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/5154084)

Comment: @AndréNeves The Site has either expired or been put up for sale, that is what message i get when i check on website availability sites.

Comment: Yeah I saw. My answer teaches you how to check if the server is the problem (which is the case) instead of your code.

Comment: yeah i actually, tested your answer but it is saying that mysql isn't installed. I am using ampps 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Check if your database is up by using the following command in a command shell:

```
mysql --host=www.victorexoticagoa.com --port=yourport --user=youruser --pass=yourpass
```

If it cannot connect, the problem is the server, not your code.

Comment: Will it not work, if i check the www.victorexoticagoa.com on url? Cos the above command is not working

Comment: @davidnoronha it should state that it's unable to connect to the server (provided of course MySQL is installed in your computer).

Comment: the service is installed through ampps. Will it not work with that?

Comment: @davidnoronha exactly what message are you getting?

Comment: It is saying there is no mysql installed and is asking me to install a package from the selected packages suggested. Doing that would probably affect my ampps mysql right?

Comment: The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: @davidnoronha your ampps MySQL is not accessible from any directory because it's not in the PATH variable. Either include it in PATH or install the MySQL suggested package, which will likely not interfere with your ampps install (you can remove the package when you're done with the command above, just to be sure it won't interfere).

Comment: OK, now all I got was an arrow below

Comment: @davidnoronha you're supposed to run it with the parameters I gave you (`--host`, `--user` etc)

Comment: I copy pasted the same code you gave, replaced the username and password, and the port with 3306, still showing me the arrow below (->)

Comment: @davidnoronha read the output. If it doesn't end with `mysql>` and a cursor for you to enter commands with, it failed to connect.

Comment: so the error lies in the db server? It just shows an arrow like this: (- >)

Comment: @davidnoronha no. Something's wrong with your command, but I don't have enough information to help you with it.

Comment: would the issue lie with the port number? I have tried giving it 3306 and 80., still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if that is the way you need to connect or the port to connect? I dont see the port (thats not supposed to be port 80 most times). Please check docs of the host and ask for details. It should be documented.